# ¿Porque el 'jQuery' se ejecuta 2 veces?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

js en donde tengo 'jQuery', el problema es que se me ejecuta dos veces. Alquien me puede explicar a que se debe y como solucionarlo por favor.
Anexo el jQuery...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#botonExportar").click(function(){
          var data = $("#producto").val();
          alert('productoBuscado='+data);
          $.post("registrosExportaciones.php",{producto:data}, function(respuesta){
               alert('todo bien..'+respuesta);
          });
      });
  });
```

Aqui esta el html...

```
     <div class="" align="right">
     <form id="registrarExportacion" action="./FPDF/generarReporte.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
       <input type="hidden" name="tipoReporte" value="detecciones">
       <input type="hidden" name="producto" id="productoBuscado" value="$producto">
       <button type="submit" id="botonExportar" class="btn btn-default btn-md exportar" name="button" style="background-color:red !important; margin-top:1%;">Exportar</button>
     </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: tenes mas código para poder ver?

Comment: Solo tengo eso en el archivo.js voy a editar para agregar el html

Comment: El botón es un submit. Entonces se enviará el formulario además de realizar la llamada AJAX. No sé si eso es a lo que te refieres con que se ejecute dos veces

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro . Al darle click al boton exportar, me manda dos veces ambas alert y como el archivo.php escribe en una base de datos, me duplica el registro.

Comment: ¿Tienes más de un botón? Va a ser más fácil si creas un [mcve] para que podamos ver el fallo.

Answer (score 3):

estas enviando el formulario 2 veces, una atraves de Ajax y otra atraves del propio formulario.

Modifica esta linea

```
<button type="submit" id="botonExportar" class="btn btn-default btn-md exportar" name="button" style="background-color:red !important; margin-top:1%;">Exportar</button>
```

Por esta

```
<button type="button" id="botonExportar" class="btn btn-default btn-md exportar" name="button" style="background-color:red !important; margin-top:1%;">Exportar</button>
```

Lo que cambiamos es el tipo de button de "submit" a "button". El tipo "submit" envia el formulario mas haya de que tengas un evento javascript asociado al mismo boton.

Answer (score 1):

Hice pruebas y no se está ejecutando dos veces el JQuery.
Se está enviando los datos dos veces:

- Con el `<form ... action="./FPDF/generarReporte.php">`
- Con `$.post("registrosExportaciones.php"...)`

¿Puedes recrearlo en [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Prueba: [https://jsfiddle.net/.../pvre3zoL/](https://jsfiddle.net/shinseiki86/pvre3zoL/)

Comment: Esto se debe a que en el archivo ./FPDF/generarReporte.php tengo un $_POST['productoBuscado'] o a que te refieres con que se envian dos veces los datos, soy nuevo usando esto y no tengo a alguien que me explique como funciona.

Comment: ¿Y en registrosExportaciones.php tambien procesas información del formulario?

Answer (score 0):

Una de las razones por qué ocurre eso es porque estás añadiendo el CDN de jQuery y tu archivo externo Js:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

De esta manera hay conflictos entre el framework y vanillaJS. Si vas a usar jQuery, no importa la versión, no debes insertar archivos .Js demás, así que solo debes dejar:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba modificando

```
$("#botonExportar").click(function(){
   .......
   ........

 })
```

por

```
 $("#botonExportar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   tu código

  })
```

Comment: Revisa [answer] para que tus respuestas sean mejor aceptadas